# Distribution of sum of two dependent variable

Tags: probability-distributions

`X` conforms to a normal distribution with mean `a` and variance `b`.

Every time I randomly generates a value of `X` first, say `x0`. If `x0` is greater than preset threshold `Q`, then I generates `Y` from another normal distribution with mean `c` and variance `d`. If `x0` is less or equal to threshold `Q`, then  stop.

Let `Z=X+Y`

I did below calculation, but that only gives me the expectation. How can I derive the distribution of `Z`?

E(Z)=E(X)+E(Y)=a+E(Y|X>Q)+E(Y|X<=Q)=a+c+0=a+c

Var(Z)=?

Comment: What is $Y$ if $X$ is less or equal to threshold $Q$? Does not defined at all?

Comment: @NCh sorry didn't make it clear. In that case Y = 0.

Comment: Use Law of total expectation for $E(Y)$. Both conditional expectations need to be multiplied by probabilities of $X>Q$ (respectively $X\leq Q$).
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Comment: @nch thanks will look into that. That only gives me the variance right? It seems Z doesn't have a typical distribution

Comment: The alternative simple way is to take $Y\sim N(c,d)$ independent of $X\sim N(a,b$, and $Z=X+Y\cdot I(X\geq Q)$, where $I(X\geq Q)$ means indicator function which is equal to 1 if $X\geq Q$ or 0 else. Then calculate $Var(Z)$ using properties of variance or simply through the second moment.